# Core Data awakeFromInsert() initialization

Tags: core-data, initialization, uuid

I want to initialise NSManagedObject with two fields *created* and *uuid*. What I'm doing is this:

```
public class Event: NSManagedObject {

   public override func awakeFromInsert() {
       self.awakeFromInsert()

       self.created = NSDate()
       self.id = UUID().uuidString
   }

}
```

I'm not sure if it is a correct way for initialisation. As far as I understand `awakeFromInsert()` is called only once in NSManagedObject lifetime, right? If *uuid* or *created* will be reinitialised then it would be a problem.